# Android Install error with release unsigned apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, gradle-release-plugin

I try to install an application on release build type and I get the generic error:
"Parse error. There was a problem while parsing the package"

Installing the debug apk works successfully.

Installing release apk with adb shows this information:

> C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb install app-release-unsigned.apk
>
> 2577 KB/s (1606360 bytes in 0.608s)
>           pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release-unsigned.apk
>
> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

This is the logcat

> V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname
>   com.android.packageinstaller 
>   I/ActivityManager: START u0
>   {act=android.intent.action.VIEW  dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/app-> > release-unsigned.apk
>   typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive
>   cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity (has
>   extras)} from uid 10019 on display 0
>
> D/CustomFrequencyManagerService:
>   acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1190400 
>   uid : 1000  pid : 961  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@4
>
> W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire() 
>   D/InputDispatcher: Focused
>   application set to: xxxx D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 22409
>   /? D/MyFiles: FileUtils::update file open count D/DisplayManager:
>   addAllDisplaysLocked() 
>   D/ActivityManager:  Launching
>   com.android.packageinstaller, updated priority
>   D/SSRM:a: DeviceInfo:: 000000000000
>   D/SSRM:a: SettingsAirViewInfo:: 000000000
>   /?
>
> W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

The module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx.yyyy.zzzzz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')        
    compile project(':SAPE.Lib')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Well, it clearly says **unsigned** in the file name. Did you try building from Android Studio using Build -> Generate Signed APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing the unsigned apk using the command

```
adb install app-release-unsigned.apk
```

When generating the signed apk remember the path to which you are saving the signed apk and install the apk from that location. It should install fine.